# Iterate over rows to determine count specific words

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem in iterating over rows in a pandas data frame.
I would need to determine for each row (which contains strings) the following:

- count of each punctuation in the string;
- count of number of capital letters.

To answer the first point, I have tried as follows with a string in order to see if the approach can work also for a dataframe:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 

from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 

t= "Have a non-programming question?"
t_low = search.lower()   
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 
  
word_tokens = word_tokenize(t_low) 
  
m = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words] 
  
m = [] 
  
for w in word_tokens: 
    if w not in stop_words: 
        m.append(w)
```

then, to count them after tokenisation:

```
import string
from collections import Counter


c = Counter(word_tokens)  

for x in string.punctuation: 
    print(p , c[x])
```

For the second point I applied to the sentence the following:

```
 sum(1 for c in t if c.isupper()))
```

However this case can be applied only for a string. Since I have a pandas data frame like the following:

```
Text



"Have a non-programming question?"
More helpful LINK!
Show SOME CODE... and so on...
```

I would like to know how I need to apply the above code in order to get same information.
Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lambda function on your DF to do that:

```
import string
def Capitals(strng):
    return sum(1 for c in strng if c.isupper())

def Punctuation(strng):
    return sum([1 for c in strng if c in string.punctuation])

df['Caps'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x:Capitals(x))
df['Punc'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x:Punctuation(x))
```

Caps is a new column with the number of uppercase letters.
Punc is a new column with the number of punctuation.
Name is the string tested.